# Open a new tab if sql query is successful

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I want to open a new tab, if the sql query was executed successfully,
I am using PHP Codeigniter.

I have tried this:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id_user);
$query = $this->db->update($user_table, $data_users); 
if($query)
{
    ?>
    <script>
        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

What should I do to open a new tab once I have updated the record.

Comment: `window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$this->db->affected_rows()` in IF condition.

Comment: Thanks This works @sameer